# Activity not working on 2.2?

Tags: android, drawable

I have used three images in layout where two are set in layout and one load from drawable at runtime. In 2.1, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1 it works fine but I am getting an error with 2.2 and 2.3.3.

Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/TopBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@+id/BottomBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ClientSide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#00000000">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/EnterName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/enterclientname"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="3dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Date" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="3dip">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ServerSide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#00000000">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ProvidedBy" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/providedby"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginRight="3dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/CenterName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/centername"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginRight="3dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/CenterAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/centeraddress" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/PersonAura"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/person" android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/OuterAura" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/outeraura"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/InnerAura" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BottomBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bar" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <Button android:id="@+id/Scan" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/Button"
        android:textSize="13sp" android:text="@string/scan"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="1dip">
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Tune" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/Button"
        android:textSize="13sp" android:text="@string/tune"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip">
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Save" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/Button"
        android:textSize="13sp" android:text="@string/saveb"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip">
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Share" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/Button"
        android:textSize="13sp" android:text="@string/share"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip">
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Settings" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/Button"
        android:textSize="13sp" android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="1dip">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my Java file.

```
public class Aura extends Activity 
{
protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

TextView mClientName, mDate, mProvidedBy, mCenterName, mCenterAddress;
ImageView mOutterAuraImage, mInnerAuraImage, mPersonAuraImage;
String mGetClientNameString;
Button mScan, mTune, mSave, mShare, mSettings;
EditText mSavedClientName;

Bitmap mBackImage, mTopImage, mBackground, mInnerImage, mNewSaving;
Bitmap mTopModifiedImage, mNewKetanImage, mSaveTakeViewBitmap, mTakeViewBitmap;
Canvas mComboImage;
FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream;
BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable, mTakeViewBitmapDrawable;
boolean mFileSendSet = false, mFirstSaveCalled = false;
float mContrast;
private ColorMatrix mColorMatrix;
Drawable mDrawable;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.aura);

    Log.v(TAG, "Brand: " + android.os.Build.BRAND);
    Log.v(TAG, "Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE);
    Log.v(TAG, "Display: " + android.os.Build.DISPLAY);
    Log.v(TAG, "ID: " + android.os.Build.ID);
    Log.v(TAG, "Model: " + android.os.Build.MODEL);
    Log.v(TAG, "Manufacturer: " + android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER);

    mClientName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EnterName);
    mDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date);
    mProvidedBy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ProvidedBy);
    mCenterName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterName);
    mCenterAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CenterAddress);
    mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
    mTune = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Tune);
    mSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);
    mShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Share);
    mSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Settings);
    mOutterAuraImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.OuterAura);
    mInnerAuraImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.InnerAura);
    mPersonAuraImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.PersonAura);
    mShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View mView) 
        {
            try
            {
                Random mRandomGenerator = new Random();

                int mInnerGeneratedRandom = mRandomGenerator.nextInt(255);
                Log.v(TAG, "mInnerGeneratedRandom" + mInnerGeneratedRandom);
                mColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();

                Drawable mDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart);
                mDrawable.setColorFilter( Color.MAGENTA, Mode.MULTIPLY );
                mInnerAuraImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);

                int mOutterGeneratedRandom = mRandomGenerator.nextInt(255);
                Log.v(TAG, "mOutterGeneratedRandom" + mOutterGeneratedRandom);
                mContrast = mOutterGeneratedRandom / 180.f;
                setContrastScaleOnly(mColorMatrix, mContrast);
                mOutterAuraImage.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mColorMatrix));

                int mPersonGeneratedRandom = mRandomGenerator.nextInt(255);
                Log.v(TAG, "mPersonGeneratedRandom" + mPersonGeneratedRandom);
                mContrast = mPersonGeneratedRandom / 180.f;
                setContrast(mColorMatrix, mContrast);
                mPersonAuraImage.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mColorMatrix));
            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryError eOutOfMemoryError)
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "OutOfMemoryError: " + eOutOfMemoryError.toString());
                System.gc();
                //((BitmapDrawable)mInnerAuraImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
                unbindDrawables(mDrawable);
            }
        }
    });
}// onCreate

private void unbindDrawables(Drawable nDrawable) 
{
    if(mDrawable != null)
    {
        mDrawable.setCallback(null);
    }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at

```
Drawable mDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart);
mDrawable.setColorFilter( Color.MAGENTA, Mode.MULTIPLY );
mInnerAuraImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
```

Would somebody help me why this happen in 2.2? What would I do with this Drawable?

My Logcat output for error:

```
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kihealer.aura/com.kihealer.aura.Aura}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.kihealer.aura.Aura.onCreate(Aura.java:83)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     ... 11 more
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     ... 23 more
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
06-01 18:59:15.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     ... 26 more
06-01 18:59:15.655: WARN/ActivityManager(74):   Force finishing activity com.kihealer.aura/.Aura
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you provide your logcat output?

Comment: @Mark Allison I have added logcat output to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of the images in your layout is causing an OutOfMemory exception, possibly @drawable/outeraura.

I would check the amount of RAM that you have assigned to the emulator, and also look at the size of your drawable images. If they are large then you will get speed and memory improvements by scaling them down to match the target screen density.

Comment: @Mark Allison How to check the amount of VM that we have assigned to the emulator. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark Allison but those images are very small in size like one is 192 KB and the others are 250 KB each. So would it exceed the RAM size?

Comment: How big do they need to be (in pixels, that is)? If they are significantly larger than they need to be then you're doing much more work than you need to because the images need resizing which is both processor & memory intensive. Also, 250K may not sound like much, but it could be significantly larger once the image has been decompressed.

Comment: @Mark Allison It need to be fit in the whole screen size. I mean fill_parent for width and height.

Comment: And what are the dimensions of the raw image? If it is significantly larger than required, it could cause you problems. Are you using a 9-patch? That could save you processor & memory resources.

Comment: @Mark Allison Dimensions of all raw images are 800 x 1200.

Comment: That's likely to be your problem, then. Each image is going to be around 4MB uncompressed, and a resize requires 3 copies. Three ImageView objects, and you're looking at almost 40MB RAM just to handle a small section of your layout. I bet if you replace all of your images in the layout with @android:color/transparent suddenly everything will work. You really need to rethink how you implement that layout. Can you combine your three ImageView objects in to a single one?

Answer (score 0):

are you using a different emulator for 2.2 and 2.3.3 with small ram sizes for each?

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
sounds like the app is running out of memory?

How large are the images?

Comment: It has the same ram size as 2.1, 2.3, 3.0 and 3.1 have then why it cause problem only with these two emulators. Thanks.

Comment: how large are the images and does the problem happen on load, or with the onClick event?

Comment: Those image are just in KB around 250 KB each